# How to add this command an alias in .bashrc "sudo vi /etc/hosts"

Tags: linux, bash

After I add this alias, there is error like this"bash: alias: vi: 未找到"(not found) when I execute source ~/.bashrc.

I add this line in the .bashrc:
alias hosts=sudo vim /etc/hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
alias hosts='sudo vim /etc/hosts'
```

Remember you need to quote it since it has ***spaces***

Also, try not to use sudo in scripts/.bashrc as its not a good practise.

Answer (score 1):

```
 alias hosts='sudo vim /etc/hosts'
```

You need to surround the command in quotes